# Vue connecting to firebase - uncaught FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initilializeApp

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following [this twitter clone (using Vue)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la-0ulfn0_M) tutorial, and on about 01:30:00 he connects his app to firebase.

1. I created firebase DataBase, and copied the firebase parameters.
2. I entered a dummy document to the Database.
3. I cloned [the GitHub repo for this project](https://github.com/dannyconnell/qwitter.git), and changed the 'firebase.js' file with the firebase parameters.

This is the `firebase.js`:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

let db = firebase.firestore()

export default db
```

And I got the following error (in chrome on 'localhost:8080'):

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initializeApp.
    at new n (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?fef0:188)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?fef0:14819)
    at n.t (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?fef0:14821)
    at new n (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?fef0:15414)
    at eval (index.js?1c42:69)
    at Component.eval [as instanceFactory] (index.js?1c42:66)
    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (index.esm.js?a40d:338)
    at Provider.getImmediate (index.esm.js?a40d:130)
    at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (index.esm.js?8d00:219)
    at FirebaseAppImpl.firebaseAppImpl.<computed> [as firestore] (index.esm.js?8d00:437)
```

4. I changed the 'firebase.js' with the example that on the Vue website.

`firebase.js`:

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

But I still get the same error (as on section 3).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the file `firebase.js` may not being loaded.  You can check it with a

`console.log('test')`

inside that file.

If it is not loading I would try changing the name form `firebase.js` to `fb.js`.

Comment: It wasn't the solution, but thanks anyways - it helped me to debug it.

Comment: I am glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the database wasn't named correctly (as demanded in the open source) - I needed to call it Qwitter.